# Workflow Question - how to send one email to "Created By" for multiple updates

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm new to SharePoint, and I only have SharePoint designer 2010.

I've been tasked with setting up a workflow wherein if there are 10 rows with one "Parent ID" and 9 of them have an updated status, to send one email for the nine rows to the "Created By"

ID 1 - Parent ID 1
ID 2 - Parent ID 1
ID 3 - Parent ID 1
ID 4 - Parent ID 1
ID 5 - Parent ID 1
ID 6 - Parent ID 1
ID 7 - Parent ID 1
ID 8 - Parent ID 1
ID 9 - Parent ID 1
ID 10- Parent ID 1

I've been able to send a status update for each change in status

> "If Current Item:Status equals New", "If Current Item:Status equals In Progress", "If Current Item:Status equals Closed"

But how do I set this structure so that if the ten rows are updated, then the creator gets 1 email instead of 10?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create a list to buffer the outgoing emails. When I update item #1, add this to the list and do nothing for a length of time (maybe 30 minutes). At the end of that time, look back through the list, compile all the edits into appropriate emails, then send.